# How to connect to a standby database which is in MOUNTED state and know the applied archive log sequence number?

Tags: database, oracle

How to connect to a standby database which is in MOUNTED state and know the applied archive log sequence number?

I want to connect to a database which is in standby mode and fire a select query to know the archive log number.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the instance with sysdba:

```
export ORACLE_SID=*database_name*
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

To get the last log file you should be able to query v$archived_log.

```
select max(sequence#)
from v$archived_log
```

Comment: Hi,

Is it possible to include this script in an asp pag?

We have more than 50 databases and it is difficult to connect to each and every time one by one.

Comment: Need a script to get details of all 50 databases in a single shot in an excel or a html or asp page. Please help me

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP, but you should be able to connect to a mounted database remotely via: sqlplus sys/<sys_password>@yoursid as sysdba. You can then issue the select I provided in my answer. Note that each database will need to have the parameter remote_login_passwordfile set appropriately (shared or exclusive I believe)

Comment: How to connect if I do not know the sys password but knows password of a read only schema which has privilege to fire select query on that dba view?